# issue designing a template handling inlineformset_factory manually in django

Tags: python, html, css, django

My inlineformset_factory was working dandily until I decided to mess with the layout.

I've created an image based form that works off the already uploaded images (and a default image in case the spaces are not occupied) instead of the somewhat boring, grey input="file" button, and I get the error: "['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']" whenever I try to either upload a new image or delete an old one, eg. it somehow broke as a result of tampering with the HTML..?

In my template I have:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% for item in formset %}
{% csrf_token %}½
<div class="media context">
  <input type="file" id="formolator" accept="image/*" style="visibility:hidden;" />
  <label for="formolator">
    {% if item.extra_img.value != 'media/default.jpg' %}
    <img src="/media/{{ item.extra_img.value }}" class="img-box" />
    delete: {{ item.DELETE }}
    {% else %}
    <img src="/media/default.jpg" class="img-box" />
    {% endif %}
  </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2 mb-2" type="submit">update</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Bonus conundrum: Aside from that, I've been trying to make the forms which show up in the template (in views I've set a limit at max_num=9) do a float:left; in a few different ways. 
Wrapping another div around the whole shebang like I've done in the template in which the images wind up upon upload to DB does not work for some reason, and I'm thinking whether it has to do with the nature of the input type, but I couldn't say.
I even tried wrapping it all in two divs out of sheer desperation and I did different permutations of the theme, alas no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem recently. I was able to correct the error by adding the following tag after the closing tag of the for-loop:

{{ formset.management_form }} where 'formset' is the name of your formset.

Comment: According to the docs, the {{ xyz.management_form }} var should sit atop of the for loop; why did you put it at the bottom? I first tried applying it below then above; while it rid me of the error, I'm returned to the form (normally it goes to the result page), only now the preview of images already uploaded disappear from the template and the default.jpg takes their place. Nothing is saved/deleted and no errors appear. I tried reading through the docs on formsets again, but as per usual the docs are somewhat cryptic to me. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Hi, I placed the tag at the bottom of the loop because the example I found used that placement. The method passed the "it works" test so I didn't dig any deeper. ;-)

Comment: Try adding {% for fld in item.hidden_fields %}{{ fld }}{% endfor %} just inside the for-loop and move the csrf_token tag outside the for-loop.

Comment: A couple of steps closer: Now I'm able to delete things again, however still unable to upload. Also it's going to the display page upon submission, as it should. I get [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}] in the CLI due to adding print(formset.errors) in the view. Currently re-reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields